# Como fazer uma consulta complexa em SQL no .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Gostaria de saber como fazer uma consulta, usando vários campos, várias tabelas com inner joins no ASP.NET MVC sem ter que colocar a string SQL no código, utilizando o Entity Framework.

No momento, sem usar a string no código, só sei fazer consultas básicas na base.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suponha um *Model* de *Produto*:

```
public class Produto 
{ 
    [Key]
    public Guid ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoriaId { get; set; }
    public Guid FabricanteId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Descricao { get; set; } 
    [Required]
    public Decimal Preco { get; set; }

    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    public virtual Fabricante Fabricante { get; set; }
}
```

Repare que `Produto` tem dois relacionamentos: `Categoria` e `Fabricante`. Normalmente o Entity Framework já é configurado para trazer todos os dados sozinho quando for solicitado pelo código. Isto é uma implementação que usa **carga preguiçosa**. Nesta implementação, ao selecionar um `Produto`, `Categoria` e `Fabricante` recebem objetos provisórios (Proxies dinâmicos). Estes objetos, ao serem solicitados a fornecer o valor de alguma propriedade (por exemplo, o nome de uma `Categoria`), são substituídos pelos objetos do *Model* propriamente dito. Neste processo, ocorrem seleções ou buscas em cache local, dependendo da situação.

## Seleções Básicas

A sentença abaixo:

```
var produtos = context.Produtos.ToList();
```

é o equivalente a fazer:

```
select * from Produtos
```

`context` é uma variável que representa o contexto da sua aplicação, objeto este de classe derivada de `DbContext`.

## Selecionando Entidades Dependentes

Para trazer também os fabricantes e categorias de cada produto, a ideia é usar o seguinte comando:

```
var produtos = context.Produtos
               .Include(p => p.Fabricante)
               .Include(p => p.Categoria)
               .ToList();
```

Que é equivalente a:

```
select * from Produtos
inner join Fabricantes on Fabricantes.FabricanteId = Produtos.FabricanteId
inner join Categorias on Categorias.CategoriaId = Produto.CategoriaId
```

A sentença `Include()`, ao contrário da carga preguiçosa, obriga o Entity Framework a trazer os dados imediatamente. Ou seja, é gerado um SQL com os *joins* especificados acima.

Para colocar condições na sua seleção, use `Where()`:

```
var produtos = context.Produtos
               .Include(p => p.Fabricante)
               .Include(p => p.Categoria)
               .Where(p => p.Categoria.Nome == "Calçados")
               .ToList();
```

Para condições compostas, basta usar operadores lógicos, como `&&` ou então `||`:

```
var produtos = context.Produtos
               .Include(p => p.Fabricante)
               .Include(p => p.Categoria)
               .Where(p => p.Categoria.Nome == "Calçados" && p.Fabricante.Nome != "Adidas")
               .ToList();
```

## Cardinalidade N

Suponha agora que `Fabricante` seja implementado da seguinte forma:

```
public class Fabricante 
{ 
    [Key]
    public Guid FabricanteId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
}
```

Assim como um `Produto` pertence a um `Fabricante`, `Fabricante` possui vários `Produtos`. A `ICollection` acima especifica este relacionamento.

Para selecionar um `Fabricante` e seus `Produtos`, use a seguinte sentença:

```
var fabricantes = context.Fabricantes.Include(f => f.Produtos).ToList();
```

## Persistindo Dados

Para inserir um novo `Produto`, a sequência de passos a seguir faz este trabalho:

```
var produto = new Produto 
{
    ProdutoId = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Nome = "Tênis de Corrida",
    Preco = 200,
    Fabricante = context.Fabricantes.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Nome == "Adidas"),
    Categoria = context.Categorias.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Nome == "Calçados")
};

context.Produtos.Add(produto);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Repare que não se insere Ids diretamente. Ao invés, são populados objetos que possuem todas as informações que o Entity Framework precisa para realizar a inserção.

Da mesma forma, uma atualização é feita da seguinte forma:

```
var produto = context.Produtos.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Nome == "Tênis de Corrida");

produto.Preco = 250;
context.Entry(produto).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Puxa ajudou bastante! Obrigado!

Comment: @TremDoido Esta é a maneira correta de fazer. Inserção manual de IDs pode confundir o Entity Framework. Quando os dois objetos não estão carregados no contexto, ao fornecer manualmente os IDs, isto faz com que o Entity Framework pense que são duas entidades novas, tente salvá-las e gere um erro de chave duplicada. Já respondi várias perguntas aqui no SOpt sobre isso, inclusive.